# Application Logs monitor script linux to generate mail on ERROR keyword in the log file

Tags: bash, shell, logging, scripting, monitoring

I am developing a script to monitor java applications Log files and generate a mail if the logs contain "ERROR keyword" and send mail along with the printed exception on that line.
Also need to make sure that the mail for a given exception is sent only once and repetitive mails are not being sent.
Request help on this.

Below is a sample "**ERROR**" (exception) log which is generated by the java application.

```
     nsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3afe08b : name: NODE_LEFT
    
    2020-08-24 08:01:45.847  INFO 132723 --- [disco-event-worker-#102] nsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3afe08b : waNodes: 1
    
    2020-08-24 08:01:45.849  INFO 132723 --- [exchange-worker-#103] .i.p.c.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager : Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=11, minorTopVer=0], force=false, evt=NODE_LEFT, node=a8161e0e-1441-4f48-b80a-d60c48a46dc8]
2020-08-24 08:01:46.121 ERROR 132723 --- [query-#134] o.a.i.i.p.q.h.t.GridMapQueryExecutor     : Failed to execute local query.

 

org.apache.ignite.cache.query.QueryCancelledException: The query was cancelled while executing.

                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridMapQueryExecutor.onQueryRequest0(GridMapQueryExecutor.java:504)

                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridMapQueryExecutor.onQueryRequest(GridMapQueryExecutor.java:353)

                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridMapQueryExecutor.onMessage(GridMapQueryExecutor.java:210)

                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridMapQueryExecutor$2.onMessage(GridMapQueryExecutor.java:170)

                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$ArrayListener.onMessage(GridIoManager.java:2333)

                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1556)

                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1184)

                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:125)

                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1091)

                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

 

2020-08-24 08:01:46.149 ERROR 132723 --- [query-#136] o.a.i.i.p.q.h.t.GridMapQueryExecutor     : Failed to execute local query.
```

Comment: What have you developed so far? Please update your question with the code.